# Converting international format numbers to the German format in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this column named display.

| Display |
| --- |
| <5.78 |
| <0.03/ |

I was trying to convert it into German format like it will show:

| Display |
| --- |
| 5,78 |
| 0,03 |

Below is the query :

```
CREATE TABLE Customer (
    CustomerID int NOT NULL,
    LastName varchar(255),
    FirstName varchar(255),
    Address varchar(255),
    City varchar(255),
    display varchar(500),
    PRIMARY KEY (CustomerID)
);

INSERT INTO Customer VALUES (101, 'Tom B. Erichsen', 'Skagen 21', 'Stavanger', 'Norway', '<5.78');
INSERT INTO Customer VALUES (102, 'Tom', 'Riddle', 'UK', 'London', '<0.03/');
INSERT INTO Customer VALUES (104, 'Tom', 'Riddle', 'UK', 'London', 'auto.met');
```

And the query I used for converting into German format using Oracle.

```
select FORMAT(cast(display as int),'N', 'de-de') from Customer;
```

It's giving me

> ORA-00904: "FORMAT": invalid identifier.

I understand I need to replace then non numeric characters before formatting.

```
Select display, replace(replace(display, '<' , ' ') , '/' , ' ') from customer;
```

I tried many things but couldn't solve. Can someone please help with this?

Comment: Why are you storing numbers as strings, with non numeric characters around them?

Comment: That's how it's stored in customer database. Their requirement is to convert in German format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if this helps. Basically, it

- replaces all that's not a *digit* or a *dot* with an empty string (that's regexp)
- replaces dots with commas

So:

```
SQL> select customerid,
  2    display,
  3    replace(regexp_replace(display, '[^[:digit:]\.]', ''), '.', ',') new_display
  4  from customer;

CUSTOMERID DISPLAY    NEW_DISPLAY
---------- ---------- ------------
       101 <5.78      5,78
       102 <0.03/     0,03

SQL>
```

Comment: what if we have a data like this also in the display column 'auto.met' ? *please check the column i have edited it*

Answer (score 2):

You can trim the unexpected characters from it and then use `TO_NUMBER` to convert it from a string to a number and `TO_CHAR` to convert the number back to a string and specify the `NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS` to set the radix and thousands separator for each conversion:

```sql
SELECT display,
       TO_CHAR(
         TO_NUMBER(
           RTRIM( LTRIM( display, '<' ), '/' ),
           '99999990D99',
           'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS=.,'
         ),
         'FM99999990D99',
         'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS=,.'
       ) AS display_german
FROM   Customer;
```

Which outputs:

> | DISPLAY | DISPLAY_GERMAN |
> | --- | --- |
> | <5.78 | 5,78 |
> | <0.03/ | 0,03 |

Answer (score 0):

If *there's no dot* **but** *between digits* for the whole data set, then use

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(
                 REGEXP_REPLACE(display,'[^0-9.]'),
                 'FM99999990D99','NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS=,.'
       ) AS "Display" 
  FROM customer
```

in order to extract the parts such as `5.78`, `0.03` etc. , then convert them to the desired numeric format(`5,78`, `0,03` etc).

**Edit** : if lately added type of values exist for the display, then convert the query to a conditional one such as

```
SELECT CASE WHEN REGEXP_REPLACE(display,'[^0-9]') IS NOT NULL THEN
       TO_CHAR(
                 REGEXP_REPLACE(display,'[^0-9.]'),
                 'FM99999990D99','NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS=,.'
       ) END AS "Display" 
  FROM customer
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=7cc1772e0fa053e0178fb15e202aae47)</kbd>